# Не работает callback_query_handler в тг боте

Tags: база-данных, telegram-bot, callback

у меня в тг боте есть колбек кнопка, но функция не улавливает, и кнопка не работает:

```
async def del_elem(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    elem = callback.data.split()[1]
    print(elem)
    await sq_db.sql_del(elem)
    await callback.answer(text=f"Элемент {elem} удалён", show_alert=True)


async def del_run(message: types.Message):
    read = await sq_db.sql_rd()
    for elem in read:
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, elem[0], f'Описание: {elem[1]}\n Название картинки: {elem[2]}',\
                             reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton(f'Удалить {elem[2]}',\
                                                                                          callback_data=f'del {elem[2]}')))
        print(f'del {elem[2]}')
```

Print я добавил, чтобы отдебажить, в функции del_run всё выводится, а вот в ф-ции del_elem нет, следовательно она даже не запускается
Вот так я регистрирую ф-ции:

```
dp.callback_query_handler(del_elem, Text(startswith='del '))
dp.register_message_handler(del_run, commands='Удалить')
```

Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что я неправильно регистрировал колбек функцию, правильно будет так:
dp.register_callback_query_handler(del_elem, Text(startswith='del '))